# Geth modes for address balance

Tags: balances, rpc

After some research I saw that there are several types of synchronizations for the geth client: full sync, fast sync and light sync.
If I want juste check the balance of an address what is the lightest mode I can use?
I also heard from the parity option: parity --no-ancient-blocks, would this help for the sync time and still allow the RPC node to know the balance of an address ?
And is there also options that stop the synchronisation of new blocks since I didn't need new blocks until a certain time and also don't want to wast disk space

Answer (score 0):

- The light mode should work to get balances. In this mode the client stores the minimal data, and it queries another node when the data needed is missing.
- fast and full node should work. It requires a server with good IO and lots of space. It takes a while to sync, event the fast mode.

Parity was renamed to OpenEthereum and later deprecated. It is no longer supported.